# How do I figure out this comma error in my SQL code?

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to run a set of subqueries but not sure what the issue is.

```
select 
    can, 
    sum(case when tax_year = 2018 then qty_req else 0 end) as TY18_esig,
    (select sum(case when tax_year = 2018 then qty_req else 0 end) as TY18_esig_unltd 
     from RPT_PCG_CART_CUR 
     where PRODUCT in ('eSignature Unlimited for ProSeries'),
    sum(case when tax_year = 2019 then qty_req else 0 end) as TY19_esig
from 
    RPT_PCG_CART_CUR
where 
    product IN ('eSignature Bank Jan 1 - Dec 31 2020', 'eSignature Unlimited for Lacerte')
    and cart_type = 'TRANSACTED'
group by 1
order by 1
```

The errors I get are:

> [Code: 4856, SQL State: 42601]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","

or

> [Code: 4818, SQL State: 0A000]  [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Subqueries in the SELECT or ORDER BY are not supported if the subquery is not part of the GROUP BY

Comment: The third "column" is a `(select .....` which is **missing** an end round bracket : the `in` condition lists a value in brackets - but it should be terminated by **two** brackets (to close the `(select ......` part, too).

Comment: Thanks I corrected this.  Any thoughts on the group by issue?

Comment: `group by 1` does nothing

Comment: Doesn't it group by CAN since there is an aggregate

Comment: You need table aliases

Comment: replace `group by 1` with `group by can`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you are missing a closing parenthesis / round bracket on your scalar subquery.

You should have two closing parens on this line before the comma:

```
where PRODUCT in ('eSignature Unlimited for ProSeries')),
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still getting the folowing error:                 [Code: 4818, SQL State: 0A000]  [Vertica][VJDBC](4818) ERROR: Subqueries in the SELECT or ORDER BY are not supported if the subquery is not part of the GROUP BY